# How to display data stored in sharedPrefernces to the user in listView?

Tags: android

I have stored some data in sharedpreferences in one activity, I want to display the stored data to the user in another activity. How do I do this?

Comment: You mean another activity within your application or an activity of another application?

Comment: Another activity within my application

Answer (score 0):

If you want display all stored data in listview or recycler first of all you should get all data and save that in list.

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet()){
if (entry.getValue() instanceof String) {
    strings.add((String) entry.getValue());
}
}
arrayToStoreStrings = strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]);
```

now you can pass strings to an adapter.
if you want use listview instead of recycler view check this link.
[ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/ListView)

Comment: please, can you explain me what is happening in the code !!

Answer (score 0):

The SharedPreferences are available in all of your Activities.
You have only to call PreferenceManager's getDefaultSharedPreferences:

```
 val listOfPreferences:MutableList<Pair<String,String>> = mutableListOf()
 val preferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext)
 val preferenceKeys=preferences.all
 preferenceKeys.forEach(){
            entry -> listOfPreferences.add(Pair(entry.key,entry.value.toString()))
            }

        // do whatever you want with key-value pair list
```